# Python How to Decompress a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary with:

```
inds = [0,   3,   7,   3,   3,   5, 1]

vals = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]

d = {'inds': inds, 'vals': vals}
```

> print(d) will get me: {'inds': [0, 3, 7, 3, 3, 5, 1], 'vals': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0,
>   7.0]}

As you can see, inds(keys) are not ordered, there are dupes, and there are missing ones: range is 0 to 7 but there are only 0,1,3,5,7 distinct integers. I want to write a function that takes the dictionary (d) and decompresses this into a full vector like shown below. For any repeated indices (3 in this case), I'd like to sum the corresponding values, and for the missing indices, want 0.0.

```
# ind:  0    1    2    3*    4    5    6    7
x == [1.0, 7.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 3.0]
```

Trying to write a function that returns me a final list... something like this:

```
def decompressor (d, n=None):
    final_list=[]
    for i in final_list:
        final_list.append()
    return(final_list)

# final_list.index:  0    1    2    3*    4    5    6    7
# final_list = [1.0, 7.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: share your code with errors.

Comment: Your problem statement is not quit clear, Could you elaborate on your sample code please!?

Comment: @SadiaArif added more context

Comment: Cryptic questions get cyptic answers: `[d.get(i, 0) for d in [{k:sum(v for _, v in g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(zip(inds, vals)), lambda x:x[0])}] for i in range(max(d))]` and make sure to `from itertools import groupby` first...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - it's better than nothing certainly, thank you. I've tried this, but this only gets me [1.0, 7.0, 0, 5.0, 0, 6.0, 0], not [1.0, 7.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 3.0]

Comment: @yc_bozo fixed it, try again

Comment: why are u iterating over empty list? and how would you append list by giving 0 argument.

Answer (score 1):

Some things are still not clear to me but supposing you are trying to make a list in which the maximum index is the one you can find in your inds list, and you want a list as a result you can do something like this:

```
inds = [0,   3,   7,   3,   3,   5, 1]
vals = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
#initialize a list of zeroes with lenght max index
res=[float(0)]*(max(inds)+1)
#[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

#Loop indexes and values in pairs
for i, v in zip(inds, vals):
    #Add the value to the corresponding index
    res[i] += v
print (res)
#[1.0, 7.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 3.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it,

```
xyz = [0.0 for x in range(max(inds)+1)]
for i in range(max(inds)):
    if xyz[inds[i]] != 0.0:
        xyz[inds[i]] += vals[i]
    else:
        xyz[inds[i]] = vals[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

inds = [0,   3,   7,   3,   3,   5, 1]

vals = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]

## first you have to initialise the dictionary , ranging from min to max value in the inds list

```
    max_id = max(inds)
    min_id = min(inds)
    my_dict={}
    i = min_id
    while i <= max_id:
        my_dict[i] = 0.0
        i = i+1
    for i in range(len(inds)):
        my_dict[inds[i]] += vals[i]
```

my_dict = {0: 1.0, 1: 7.0, 2: 0, 3: 11.0, 4: 0, 5: 6.0, 6: 0, 7: 3.0}